# How to handle signal once in many threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C# I have multiple objects, each with its own thread, that can perform an operation based on outside signal. All of the object keep a list of all other objects.
I need the signal that arrived to be performed only in single object in single thread. This signal will bring to the deletion of all objects so multiple signals won't arrive for the same object.
It's *most likely* the signal will arrive for all of them in the same time, but there can be late ones. As the signal will bring to the destruction of all of them and will not be delivered to destroyed ones, latencies can be ignored.
I though of doing `lock(this)` and then lock on each object in the list but I don't know how to perform lock without creating a scope for it (meaning manual unlock, not when the lock scope ends).
Additional problem is that if already one has started locking and the other one tries to lock it, it will just wait and not ignore it.
Also, I have no control on the `Thread` objects and even if there is a way to retrieve them any touch on the `Thread` object will likely crash the application. Answers like pausing all other threads will not work.
So how do I get the signal acted upon by exactly one object and ignore by the rest of them?

Comment: several things: at the very least, please provide some pseudo code of how your object(s) get a message and how they destroy other objects and/or themselves. What are your objects doing? Who will receive the late signals if all the objects are destroyed?

Comment: Furthermore, how will the object that receives the message know about all the other objects that need to be deleted?

Comment: I don't know how this works... It's a C++ framework that uses embedded .NET framework. it calls a method in my object when the signal is received an I should call destroy method when I want it destroyed. I do keep a list of all object in all my objects. When an object is destroyed all it's references are set to null somehow.

Comment: Can you provide the general interface of how this operates? I.e. how does an object receive a message in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a parent thread that keeps track of what has been processed.  When a thread receives a new signal, you can ask the parent if that signal has been processed already.  If not, process it and parent locks the others out.

You could also look at using a message queue, and each signal would only be picked up by one thread.

Comment: The parent thread is a good idea. I will just mark one of the threads as parent when its constructed and pass it to all other threads that join to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what's going on now, but correct me if this is wrong:

- presumably all your objects are of the same type
- the list of objects is static (if not, then consider doing it to be more efficient)
- any object can receive the signal, but only one will process it.

So if we assume that you each object has a method to receive a signal, then I would think this might be a decent design:

```
public class Thing
{
    private static volatile bool _tooLate = false;
    private static List<Thing> _theWorld; // contains everything
    private static readonly object _sync = new object();

    public Thing(){/*...*/}

    // a static method to process the signal
    public static void ProcessSignal(Signal signal)
    {
        // make sure you're not late to the party
        if(signal == signal.DestroyTheWorld && !_tooLate)
        {
            // You won't destroy the world yet... but you'll give it a shot!
            BringAboutTheDestruction();
        }
    }

    // a static method to bring about the destruction of the world! MUAHAHAHAHA
    public static void BringAboutTheDestruction()
    {
        // you might not be late for the party, 
        // but you still have to get past the doorman
        lock(_sync)
        {
            // you finally got in, but you might get kicked out!
            if(!_tooLate)
            {
                // Apocalypse now!!! There is no turning back
                foreach(Thing t in _theWorld)
                {
                    t.Destroy();
                }
                _theWorld.Clear();
            }
            _tooLate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the EventWaitHandle class. Each thread has two of these, one when the thread needs to do something, and one for closing all the threads. The first is local to the thread, the second is global:

```
void CreateThreads ()
{
   global_event = new EventWaitHandle (false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

   for each thread to create
   {
     create thread a pass the global_event object
   }
}

void ThreadProc (EventWaitHandle global_event)
{
  create local_event; // this is set when the thread needs to do something

  bool quit = false;

  while (!quit)
  {
    switch (EventWaitHandle.WaitAny (new WaitHandle [] { global_event, local_event })
    {
    case 0: // global 
      shut down other threads
      quit = true;
      break;

    case 1: // local
      do local signal processing
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The EventResetMode.AutoReset flag means that only one out of all the threads waiting on the event will be released. Of course, you can't predict which one.